# JavaScript Function is not getting executed because of if-else statements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a code where the services are coming from database into `<li></li>` tags.

Only few of the services are active currently and if an user selects a service and if that service is active then proceed and if not then an alert message should be displayed.

I have no idea why do this `function validation()` not getting executed.
Any help will be appreciated

below is the code i am working on:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function validation() {
        var category = document.getElementById("category").value;
        category = category.trim();
        if (category == "") {
            alert("Please Select Category.");
            return;
        } else {
            var limiter = ["Electrician", "Photographer", "Printing Press", "Website Designer", "Web developer", "DJ Music", "Coaching Classes", "Civil Contractor", "Computer Hardware Services"];
            var limiter_count = limiter.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < limiter_count; i++) {
                if (category == limiter[i]) {
                    document.getElementById("form1").action = "categoryforms.php";
                    document.getElementById("form1").submit();
                    //loop should be terminated
                } else {
                    var alrt = "We will soon be launching our service in " + category + ", kindly stay tuned...";
                    alert(alrt);
                    //loop should be terminated here also
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

and the form form is:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="form1" id="form1"  >
    <input type="text" name="category" id="category" value="<?php echo $category; ?>" />

    <ul id="categorymenu" class="mcdropdown_menu">

    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM  category";
        $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql);

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)){
        ?>
            <li rel="<?php echo $row["category"]; ?>" value="<?php echo $row["category"]; ?>" ><?php echo $row["category"]; ?> </li>
            <?php
        }
    ?>
    </ul>

    <input id="button" type="button" value="Send "  class="serch" onClick="javascript:validation()">
</form>
```

Comment: Step 1: Format the code readably, to make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Your code is fully working. I just test it on IE console debugger and after press submit button it skip into javascript method.. So try to check if you have correct link to javascript file.. Lukas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need for-loop, use [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to check element exists in array or not.

> The `indexOf()` method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or `-1` if it is not present.

*Script*

```
function validation() {
    var category = document.getElementById("category").value;
    category = category.trim();

    if (category == "") {
        alert("Please Select Category.");
        return;
    }

    var limiter = ["Electrician", "Photographer", "Printing Press", "Website Designer", "Web developer", "DJ Music", "Coaching Classes", "Civil Contractor", "Computer Hardware Services"];

    var index = limiter.indexOf(category);
    if (index > -1) {
        document.getElementById("form1").action = "categoryforms.php";
        document.getElementById("form1").submit();
        //loop should be terminated

    } else {
        var alrt = "We will soon be launching our service in " + category + ", kindly stay tuned...";
        alert(alrt);
        //loop should be terminated here also
    }
}
```